# how to detect visitors browser by javascript code in MacBook, PC, IOS and andrroid

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser

one of the page of my web application does not work if it is accessed from SAFARI browser from MacBook /PC / IOS

So I am detecting the browser fin that page and  if the users is accessing the page from SAFARI I am telling them to use another browser. The code i have used is

```
if (isSafari) {
 document.getElementById("safari").style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'none';
} 
else {
  document.getElementById("safari").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'block';
}
```

But it only detects browser if it is used from PC/ or Mac. But if the user uses Mobile/Iphone/Ipad or tab this code does not Browser.

How do I detect visitors browser regardless of which device he/she using.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);
```

SO this is the final output.

```
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// for mobile 
var iOS = !!ua.match(/iPad/i) || !!ua.match(/iPhone/i);
var webkit = !!ua.match(/WebKit/i);
var iOSSafari = iOS && webkit && !ua.match(/CriOS/i);

if (isSafari || iOSSafari) {
 document.getElementById("safari").style.display = 'block';
 document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'none';
} 
else {
  document.getElementById("safari").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("other").style.display = 'block';
}
```

if you put this above your code it should work. If you have more questions I will be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can check the user's Agent

```
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
```

output :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
```